# Ending an activity and calling another when countdown timer ends

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I am making an exam application in which a user can attempt questions from a chosen subject area. For instance assuming there are 20 questions to be answered by the user. As it is now, when I start the activity which presents the question and set of options to be chosen from to the user, the countdown timer starts. What I want to do now is that if the user fails to answer all the 20 questions before the time is over, this should automatically trigger another activity which calculates the user's exam score and displays the result. What is the best way to implement this? I want to be able to disallow the user from continuing with the exam once the time is up. Please any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at CountDownTimer (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html) you can do something like this with it:

```
 new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

     public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

     }

     public void onFinish() {
         // start another activity here!
     }
  }.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using Timer()

You can start new activity when timer ends. You set up in milliseconds. 
In order to start new activity, you should run on UI thread though.

```
timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() { 
public void run() {
 yourActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
   public void run(){
   }        
 }
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

If what your asking is what to do after the timer is up and not how to implement the timer then you can start a new actvity like so

```
if(timer <= 0)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, YourNewActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);  
    finish();
}
```

you can also do this from with in any of the methods of your current activity by passing the context through.

```
public void myMethod(Context mContext)
{
     if(timer <= 0)
     {
         Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, YourNewActivity.class);
         mContext.startActivity(intent);
         ((Activity)mContext).finish();
     }
}
```

Dont forget to finish() the activity other wise the user might be able to just press the back button and restart the questions.